# Application/method of transferring large files

Tags: file-synchronization, data-transfer

Some friends and myself were wanting to start up a YouTube channel which would involve all three of us routinely recording large amounts of video and audio, and getting that video and audio to one specific person's computer.

The specific person uses a laptop and can't keep the laptop powered on continuously, so the software should support the connection being interrupted during the transfer of a large file. It should resume the transfer without issue.

We do not want to use cloud storage for the cost, but the concept of automatically syncing across clients appeals to us.

Two of the three of us are technical (myself, and the owner of the destination laptop), but one of the three of us is not technical, and we are geographically removed, so something easy for a transmitting user to setup/maintain for the non-technical user is preferred.

Ideally once the file is transferred/verified, the file on the transferer's computer is automatically deleted (not required, just would be nice).

We prefer a free solution, but could spend some money (<=$30) if it was a one-time purchase for us collectively (such as a server program on the destination computer).

One client (uploader) has to be Windows, the other two can be either, but Windows is slightly preferred.

Comment: What OSes must be supported? First thing coming to my mind would be [git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/), but I'm not 100% sure it meets your needs.

Comment: @Izzy Fair question; I forgot to mention that. I think two of us are flexible, but one of the three of us (the non-technical) has to use Windows. Editing the question to reflect this.

Comment: Git-Annex is working cross-platform AFAIR. Not using it myself, so I cannot go into depth with an answer, but you might wish to take a look behind the link. And give the non-techy a nice Linux desktop (e.g. Mint or [Zorin](https://zorinos.com/), which both should be friendly to non-techies – with the latter he probably won't even note, as it can be made looking very Windows like :)